# Push to personal VPS using Github Actions

Tags: git, docker, github, ssh, github-actions

I'm using `appleboy/ssh-action@master`, I set up a github action that tries to pull changes on my server after a push to github.

```
name: Deploy to VPS
on:
  push:
    branches: [master, dev]

jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Deploy App
        uses: appleboy/ssh-action@v0.1.2
        with:
          host: ${{ secrets.HOST }}
          username: ${{ secrets.USERNAME }}
          port: ${{ secrets.PORT }}
          password: ${{ secrets.PASS }}
          script: |
            cd myfolder
            git pull
```

I've used password authentication above, I also used ssh authentication with `key: ${{ secrets.SSHKEY }}`
instead of a password.

Both the above throw me an error :

```
Run appleboy/ssh-action@v0.1.2
/usr/bin/docker run --name 645231_39754c --label 48c8ce --workdir /github/workspace --rm -e INPUT_HOST -e INPUT_USERNAME -e INPUT_PORT -e INPUT_PASSWORD -e INPUT_SCRIPT -e INPUT_PASSPHRASE -e INPUT_SYNC -e INPUT_USE_INSECURE_CIPHER -e INPUT_CIPHER -e INPUT_TIMEOUT -e INPUT_COMMAND_TIMEOUT -e INPUT_KEY -e INPUT_KEY_PATH -e INPUT_FINGERPRINT -e INPUT_PROXY_HOST -e INPUT_PROXY_PORT -e INPUT_PROXY_USERNAME -e INPUT_PROXY_PASSWORD -e INPUT_PROXY_PASSPHRASE -e INPUT_PROXY_TIMEOUT -e INPUT_PROXY_KEY -e INPUT_PROXY_KEY_PATH -e INPUT_PROXY_FINGERPRINT -e INPUT_PROXY_CIPHER -e INPUT_PROXY_USE_INSECURE_CIPHER -e INPUT_SCRIPT_STOP -e INPUT_ENVS -e INPUT_DEBUG -e HOME -e GITHUB_JOB -e GITHUB_REF -e GITHUB_SHA -e GITHUB_REPOSITORY -e GITHUB_REPOSITORY_OWNER -e GITHUB_RUN_ID -e GITHUB_RUN_NUMBER -e GITHUB_RETENTION_DAYS -e GITHUB_ACTOR -e GITHUB_WORKFLOW -e GITHUB_HEAD_REF -e GITHUB_BASE_REF -e GITHUB_EVENT_NAME -e GITHUB_SERVER_URL -e GITHUB_API_URL -e GITHUB_GRAPHQL_URL -e GITHUB_WORKSPACE -e GITHUB_ACTION -e GITHUB_EVENT_PATH -e GITHUB_ACTION_REPOSITORY -e GITHUB_ACTION_REF -e GITHUB_PATH -e GITHUB_ENV -e RUNNER_OS -e RUNNER_TOOL_CACHE -e RUNNER_TEMP -e RUNNER_WORKSPACE -e ACTIONS_RUNTIME_URL -e ACTIONS_RUNTIME_TOKEN -e ACTIONS_CACHE_URL -e GITHUB_ACTIONS=true -e CI=true -v "/var/run/docker.sock":"/var/run/docker.sock" -v "/home/runner/work/_temp/_github_home":"/github/home" -v "/home/runner/work/_temp/_github_workflow":"/github/workflow" -v "/home/runner/work/_temp/_runner_file_commands":"/github/file_commands" -v "/home/runner/work/myproject/myproject":"/github/workspace" 48c8ce:9865421398654
======CMD======
cd myproject
git pull

======END======
2021/08/15 21:58:52 Process exited with status 1
err: fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such device or address
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @phd what do you mean?

Comment: i'll mention that its a private repo

Comment: The use of `https://` as the URL means that Git will *need* to read a user name and password from somewhere (via a credential helper). I'm not sure how this is supposed to work in a github action, or for that matter, *if* it is supposed to work. The ssh key method probably should work, but your docker setup may need some `/dev` entries that don't exist in however you are actually setting it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`appleboy/ssh-action`](https://github.com/appleboy/ssh-action) is supposed to use as parameter a `host` to contact, using the ssh key or a login/passord.

But once the connection is established, the commands done depends on the remote environment: if that git repository on the SSH-accessed remote machine has an HTTPS URL, no SSH key will be used.

Even if it has an SSH key, that still would not use any key from the ssh-action plugin.
It would use the `~remoteUser/.ssh/id_rsa` default key *already* stored on the remote server home account.
If that key is there, to allow access to the remote GitHub private repository, then you need to change its origin to use the SSH URL:

```yaml
          script: |
            cd myfolder
            git remote set-url origin git@github.com:<user>/<repo>
            # or, alternatively
            git config --global url."git@github.com:".insteadOf https://github.com/
            git pull
```